# Rails efficient way to store JavaScript object to Model?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, filepicker.io

I am using the FileStack API and the file picker gem (https://github.com/Ink/filepicker-rails). I have an Attachment model that has a :title as a string. When a file is uploaded, the URL from the FilePicker API is stored as the :title. But the gem has a onchange method that returns an event variable as a JSON object that contains attributes of the file. I use JavaScript to access those attributes but I want to find a way in Rails to store those attributes, accessed via JavaScript, in a Model so that I can access it through the rest of the Rails app.

```
<%= filepicker_js_include_tag %>

<%= simple_form_for(@attachment) do |f| %>

<%= f.filepicker_field :title, onchange: 'onUpload(event)' %>
<%= f.submit %>

<% end %>

<script>
 function onUpload(event) {
 console.log(event);
 var name = event.fpfile.filename;
 console.log(name);
}
</script>
```

Update:

So after looking into your solution and googling around I am using ajax to send the data via routes to the controller. Below is my updated Javascript as well as the route and controller. When I render and inspect the @foo instance variable it is nil. So my data isn't getting passed properly. Furthermore, this whole process from the firing of the Javascript function to displaying the index view is now very very slow. I think I have the right idea after viewing your solution and doing more digging but I'm missing something and/or overcomplicating this. Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
 <script>
   function onUpload(event) {
   var name = event.fpfile.filename;
   jQuery.ajax({
   data : { data_value: event },
   type: 'post',
   url: "/attachment/index"
  });
 }
</script>
```

Route

```
post 'attachments/' => 'attachment#index'
```

Controller

```
def index
    @attachments = Attachment.all
    @foo = params[:data_value]
end
```

View (returns nil)

```
<%= raise @foo.inspect %>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `Postgres 9.3` or above you should consider using the `hstore` module and creating a `JSON` column. In a migration you can do:

```
add_column :your_model, :your_attribute, :json
```

And then you can just update `YourModel.your_attribute => {'your': 'JSON here'}`

Docs here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json

If you're using `MySQL` it's tricky, but doable. You have to create a text column and save the `JSON` as a string, and parse it every time you interact with it. Postgres is definitely better at handling `JSON`. I realize that this answer relies on an assumption, so if you're not using one of the two data stores mentioned, let me know and I'll pull it down.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I use postgres since I'm using Heroku. So how would I pass in the JavaScript object I obtain in my function above? The variable name?

Comment: You would have to post it to a route and set up a controller action to find the object in question and update the attribute.

Comment: You can't do it only with Javascript.

Comment: Something is working because this happens in the terminal
`Processing by AttachmentsController#create as */*
Parameters: {"data_value"=>"discussion_technology.doc"}`
I have @foo = params[:data_value] defined in the index action but when I attempt to view its contents via <%= puts @foo %> in the index.html.erb it is nil. Not sure what I am missing. I also updated my route as follows `post 'attachments/:data_value' => 'attachment#index'`. I need assistance in how to properly send data_value to the index controller via the route. Thanks!

Comment: I do get this in my terminal `Unpermitted parameter: data_value`

Comment: You need to read about strong_params and save the name object as JSON. Not much else I can add with this information.

Comment: Also, I think you're outside the scope of the original question. You should probably ask a new on for this functionality.